# Date Field validation issues

Tags: drupal-7

The date field doesn't get validated for a format like 2013-02-13, but it works for 2013-12-12. Leading zero seems to be creating problem in any node form. I have "clientside validation" module on. I couldn't find anything related to this bug/issue anywhere, so I am posting here.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is issue in clientside validation js due to using of parseInt for validating a month & day value of a date. just replace with it

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("dateFormat", function(value, element, param) {
      var parts = value.split(param.splitter);
      var expectedpartscount = 0;
      var day = parseInt(parts[param.daypos], 10);
      var month = parseInt(parts[param.monthpos], 10);
      month = month - 1;
      var year = parseInt(parts[param.yearpos], 10);
      var date = new Date();
      var result = true;

 /* if (day.toString().length !== parts[param.daypos].length){
        result = false;
      }
      if (month.toString().length !== parts[param.monthpos].length){
        result = false;
      }*/
      if (year.toString().length !== parts[param.yearpos].length){
        result = false;
      }
      if (param.yearpos !== false){
        expectedpartscount++;
        date.setFullYear(year);
        if (year !== date.getFullYear()) {
          result = false;
        }
      }
      if (param.monthpos !== false) {
        expectedpartscount++;
        date.setMonth(month);
        if (month !== date.getMonth()) {
          result = false;
        }
      }
      if (param.daypos !== false) {
        expectedpartscount++;
        date.setDate(day);
        if (day !== date.getDate()) {
          result = false;
        }
      }
      if (expectedpartscount !== parts.length) {
        result = false;
      }
      return this.optional(element) || result;
    }, jQuery.format('The date is not in a valid format'));
```

Comment: Thanks Dilipkumar it worked. And Thanks kiamlaluno for editions.